# change X-axis max and min on multiple charts including hidden charts

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change the x-axis max and min values on multiple charts on the same sheet including charts that are hidden (.visible=false).

This code works, but not, if the graph is hidden:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("CISGraph").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chart Settings").Range("B3").Value
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chart Settings").Range("B2").Value
```

I want to change it to something like below to bypass selecting it, but it doesn't work.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("CISGraph").Charts("CISGraph").Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = _
  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chart Settings").Range("B3").Value
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("CISGraph").Charts("CISGraph").Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = _
  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chart Settings").Range("B2").Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chart embedded in a `ChartObject` is accessed via its `Chart` property:

```
Dim wsSettings As Worksheet

Set wsSettings = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chart Settings")

With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("CISGraph").Chart.Axes(xlCategory)

    .MinimumScale = wsSettings.Range("B3").Value

    .MaximumScale = wsSettings.Range("B2").Value

End With
```